# The img is showing broken on the search angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, wordpress

I m working wordpress site,With autorent theme.I have a plugin name Angular based filtering plugin which gives the serch recult,The problem is this filter shows broken images on search result  this is the code which renders featured images

```
<img  data-ng-src="{{ post.post_thumbnail }}"/>
```

On google console it shows this

```
<img data-ng-src="false" src="false">
```

this is the link to my [site](https://www.seodemoweb.com/click-motor.com/cars/)

Thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

Problem is about data.

Somehow your post object contains false instead of correct url to the image

```
post_permalink : "https://www.seodemoweb.com/click-motor.com/product/fiat-negro-2/",
post_thumbnail :  false
post_title     : "fiat negro"
```

So check your controller and correct the data
Hope this helps

Comment: then the only reason for this. Your variable is empty. Place span with same binding there and check variable value (ng-bind) if span will be empty than debug your code and try to figure out why there is no data

Comment: If i dont put any featured image,It automatically picks up the placeholder image

Comment: Not sure you are talking about. Ng-src can only refresh src attribute with provided value. So it is the only metter of the value :) you passed into.

Comment: <img  data-ng-src="post.post_thumbnail"/>
                            <div class="overlay-shadow">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <a href="{{ post.post_permalink }}" class="btn white"><?php _e('Read More','autorent'); ?></a>

Comment: "00C"
additional_attrs
:
""
comment_count
:
0
post_content
:
"<strong>TEMPORADA ALTA DESDE HASTA CUANDO 
↵-Descripción del producto  
↵-Fotos  
↵-Datos del cancelación 
↵-Datos deposito</strong>"
post_date
:
"2017-11-07 18:46:19"
post_permalink
:
"https://www.seodemoweb.com/click-motor.com/product/rueda-airwheel-q5-2/"
post_thumbnail
:
false
post_title
:
"RUEDA AIRWHEEL Q5"
price
:
"343435"

This is from your post object. As you see thumbnail = false; check your data and all will be ok

Comment: That's i cant figure out why it is false,Can you please point me to direction,Where i can search,Thankyou fou your time

Comment: find AtmfFrontEnd controller in your js code and search there for the posts array.